# Correct use of shared_ptr for explicit library linkage

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr

I'm using http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLLand http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/16/exporting-c-classes-from-a-dll/ (as well as a few other blogs, posts, etc. but my reputation is too low to post them) to try to create a class library that I can explicitly link to.  What I'd like to do is use a std::shared_ptr to take care of rudimentary deletion of the class upon termination (or it falls out of scope).  My code compiles, but on run it keeps getting an access violation in xrefwrap.  Here's my unit test code:

```
typedef IHermes* (*pHermesFactory)();
typedef std::shared_ptr<IHermes> IHermesPtr;

using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int iReturnValue = 0;
    HINSTANCE hInstance = LoadLibrary(TEXT("Hermes.dll"));
    assert(hInstance);
    pHermesFactory pHermes = (pHermesFactory)GetProcAddress(hInstance, "HermesFactory");
    assert(pHermes);
    IHermesPtr ptrHermes(pHermes(), std::mem_fn(&IHermes::Release));
    assert(ptrHermes);

FINISH:
    if (hInstance)
        FreeLibrary(hInstance);<br/>
    return iReturnValue;
}
```

I've read the MSDN description of `shared_ptr` and `mem_fn` and have done more research on this site and others but I can't figure out what I've done that C++ doesn't like.

`IHermes` is a standard interface: `struct IHermes{ virtual void Release()=0;};`  (and that is literally the ONLY function in there at this point)

and I've implemented Release in the class that is returned by the Factory:

```
 class Hermes : public IHermes { void Release() { delete this; } }
```

and finally the factory function is:

```
 (extern "c" - declared in header not in the implementation) __cdecl(dllexport) IHermes* APIENTRY HermesFactory(){ return new Hermes; }
```

Here's where this thing is access violating (from xrefwrap):

```
template<class _Pmf,
   class _Farg0,
   class... _Ftypes>
static _Ret _Call_pmf(_Pmf _Pm, _Farg0&& _Fx0, false_type, _Ftypes&&... _Fargs)
{   // apply to (possibly smart) pointer
   return (((*_Fx0).*_Pm)(_STD forward<_Ftypes>(_Fargs)...)); <-- ACCESS VIOLATION??
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas where I've screwed up or where I can go to do more research and figure this out?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `FreeLibrary` unloads the library, and then when `main` returns the `shared_ptr` destructor runs and calls its deleter resulting in a call to `IHermes::Release`, presumably where the library used to be. Much hilarity ensues.

Comment: Don't use `TCHAR` unless you are actively porting ancient windows software.

Comment: Casey, you got it in one.  That red glow you see in the sky is not Rudolph; nope, it's due to my embarrassment over missing something so simple.